# Ubuntu's Software File Type?

Tags: files, software-installation, extension

I recently tried to install Xara as an alternative to my CorelDRAW, but the file that was downloaded was merely 18.5MB and a .package file.

I don't even know what kind of extensions do software for Ubuntu have. I am using Ubuntu 13.10. The file downloaded doesn't open (rather **tries** to open in gedit, the text editing application!).

Please tell me what kind of files I need to download that can be "executed" as applications/programmes/software in Ubuntu. Of course I can use terminals and the Software Centre but I happened to read all that was written on Xara's website and clicked on "Download for Ubuntu" and it didn't work.

Comment: serach for .deb files. It will works as an .exe file in Windows.

Comment: For vector graphics you can use Inkscape in Ubuntu

Comment: I think the extension it's .deb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question on the file type to download: Their download page does not have a special package for Ubuntu, which would be a "*.deb" file.
You would need to use a more general package file, and do some manual work to unpack it.

http://www.xaraxtreme.org/download.html

Looking at the download page, there are "binaries", but not in the common form of "packages" like *.rpm or *.deb, so nothing we can just install and run.

Seems there is some manual tweaking needed in this case.

If there were no binary packages, there could  but source packages, that need to 
be build before it can be used; Not normally what you are looking for, if there 
is an alternative.

To install xara, it turned out it was inthe standard Ubuntu package `xaralx`, in software source "multiverse".

Another common variant to install extra software that is not available by default is again not looking for files, but telling Ubuntu where to look for files (It would, in the end, look for, download and install *.deb files actually).

This can be done by adding PPAs to the software sources - Personal Package Archives, providing different software, or just different versions of standard software.

*Conclusion:* **Normally, you should not need to know this type.**:
 If you feel you do, chances are there is a better, simpler way to do it.

---

To answer what I thought was you real underlying question, in the sense of an X-Y-question (turning out to be wrong) - "How to install Xara on Ubuntu":

It is available as a normal package, you don't an extra download.
The package is called xaralx (maybe that was the confusing part) and can be installed normally:

```
sudo apt-get install xaralx
```

(The software source "multiverse" needs to be enabled)